# Adding a css class shifts my google map on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm adding a marker to my Google Map using the 'addClass()' in JQuery on the press of a button on the page. The marker is static so it rests in the center of the page when the page is dragged.

I think maybe the problem is that I'm adding the CSS class to my div that contains the map, and when the class gets added it manipulates the placement of not just the marker but the map as well.

The problem I'm having is that on my site it's shifting the map up and to the right. I've also included picture examples below.

---

Here is some of my code:

**Javascript:**

```
$("#editPinDrop").click(function() {
  var t = $(this).text();
  if ($(this).text() == "Save") {
    $("button#editPinDrop").text('Adjust Pin Location');
    // make map undraggable
    mapOptions.draggable = false;

    $marker.setMap($googlemap);
    // remove div

    // put marker back in
    initialize(true);
    //SaveCoordinates();
  } else {
    $("button#editPinDrop").text('Save');
    // make map draggable
    mapOptions.draggable = true;

    $marker.setMap(null);
    // inject the div into the map
    $('#map-canvas').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo($googlemap.getDiv());

    // init with no marker
    initialize(false);
  }
});


function initialize(hasMarker) {

  $googlemap = new window.google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  if (hasMarker) {
    var latlngs = new google.maps.LatLng(mapCoordinates.latitude, mapCoordinates.longitude); //(6.9167, 79.8473); 
    $marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlngs,
      map: $googlemap,
      title: 'My Space',
      draggable: false
    });

    $marker.setMap($googlemap);
  } else {
    $marker.setMap(null);
  }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.centerMarker {
  position: absolute;
  /*url of the marker*/
  background: url('../App_Data/Images/meetups.png') no-repeat;
  /*center the marker*/
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  /*fix offset when needed*/
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-top: -34px;
  /*size of the image*/
  height: 34px;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
  <div class="thumbnail">
    <div id="map">
      <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 380px; width: 480px"></div>
      <br />@if (Model.Address.Completed == ListingComplete.Complete) {
      <div id="addressDiv">
        <button id="addressbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          Edit Address
        </button>
        <button id="editPinDrop" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">
          Adjust Pin Location
        </button>
      </div>
      } else {
      <div id="addressDiv">
        <button id="addressbutton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
          Add Address
        </button>
        <button id="editPinDrop" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="display:none;">
          Adjust Pin Location
        </button>
      </div>
      }
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jcHqt/108/)

---

[image]

This is what it looks like after I press the adjust pin location button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that is the problem - if you follow the Fiddle's lead and use

`$('<div/>').addClass('centerMarker').appendTo($googlemap.getDiv());`

it should work.

Essentially, you are getting the existing map element, adding the class to that, and then appending it to the result of `map.getDiv()`.  From what I can tell, you actually want to be appending a new empty div with class `centerMarker` to the map.

Comment: Thanks! Please help me understand the element inside the parenthesis? It's a div in brackets with a closing character at the end!?? Why can't I just use the id "map-canvas" as my selector? Won't this 'div' selector be applied to other divs on the page, because it's generic?

Comment: Nope, won't be applied to other divs.  It's creating a new div on the fly http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2, and you are then adding that class.  If you use the selector "#map-canvas" you will instead grab the map canvas div and then add the "centerMarker" class to it (hence the movement of that div).